# Why are Sidorio chapters narrated in the present tense in Tide of Terror?

Tags: style, justin-somper, vampirates

Sidorio, the main antagonist of the Vampirates series, has several stand-alone scenes dotted through the second novel, *Tide of Terror*. Although the series as a whole is almost entirely narrated in the past tense, these scenes with Sidorio on his own (and some of his scenes with Stukeley too, IIRC) are for some reason narrated in the present tense.

**Why is the tense changed for the Sidorio scenes?** What does this inconsistency add to the tale?